# Error installing gnuplot: undefined reference to `luaL_checkint'

Tags: 14.04, gnuplot, lua

I am making an attempt to install the program `gnuplot` version 5.0.1 on `Ubuntu 14.04`. For this, I made the following steps.

```
Steps to install Gnuplot.
1) Run 'sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev', necessary for the Lua installation to run properly.
2) Download Lua.
3) In the Lua root directory, run 'make linux'.
4) In the Lua root directory, run 'make test'.
5) In the Lua root directory, run 'make install'.
6) Download gnuplot.
7) In the gnuplot root directory, run './configure --with-lua=yes'.
8) In the gnuplot root directory, run 'make'.
```

In the last step, I get the errors

```
/GNUplot/Source/gnuplot-5.0.1/src/../term/lua.trm:288: undefined reference to `luaL_checkint'
```

and

```
/GNUplot/Source/gnuplot-5.0.1/src/../term/lua.trm:254: undefined reference to `luaL_checkint'
```

Googling on this error does not seem to give me any useful hits to solve the problem...

How can I solve this?

ADDITIONAL INFORMTATION, ON REQUEST OF the user `lemonslice`:

The output of `./configure --with-lua=yes`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_npknqRCNbCM09ua3ZlSjR1X0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you put the output `configure --with-lua=yes` ? Especially the part with Lua libraries

Comment: We're sorry, but Ubuntu 14.10 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.

Comment: @Fabby. Okay. I will try with `14.04 LTS` instead and see if I get the same error. Release `14.04 LTS` is still supported, right?

Comment: Right, and what I'm running...  Are you using the same `/home` partition when you reinstall?  Or do you wipe everything and start from scratch?

Comment: @Fabby. It's another computer and I wipe everything and start from scratch.

Comment: @Fabby. I am, unfortunately, getting the same error with `14.04 LTS`. I will add the tag `14.04`. Will this post be taking off hold?

Comment: Voted to re-open.

Comment: @lemonslice I just put the output of `./configure --with-lua=yes` there.

Comment: Check `Line 3731: lua is not found.` You should install lua libs from a debian package or add the location of the lua you have built from source to your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable.

Comment: @lemonslice As I tried to explain with the steps I mentioned in my post, I most certainly did install `lua` ;). I downloaded it from http://www.lua.org/download.html. So I guess it might be the location of lua problem you mentioned. I'll try to solve this, but I, unfortunately, do not have a lot experience with stuff like that. Could you perhaps be more specific in what exactly I should add to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and how? Thanks!

Comment: @lemonslice I installed `Lua 5.3.1`. In the `config.log` it says I need the file `lua.pc`, but it didn't come with the `lua-5.3.1.tar.gz`. Supposedly, the `lua.pc` is in the corresponding development files, but I cannot find the `Lua 5.3.1` development files on the Lua website.

Comment: It is missing from the download (cf. http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-02/msg00814.html), you might want to stick to some pre-packaged lua version that provides the `.pc` file (as `liblualib-dev`).

Comment: @lemonslice The `liblualib-dev` does not exist. I installed `liblua5.2-dev` and I still have the same problem :(. But I think that on  lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-02/msg00814.html they say that as of version 5.2, `lua.pc` is dropped. I'll try to install an older version then. Guess `gnuplot` is not exactly using the latest version of `lua` yet :(.

Comment: @lemonslice Installing `liblua5.1-0-dev` also didn't help. Still get the same error.

Comment: What is wrong with the `gnuplot` that is already in the repos?  Why not `apt-get install gnuplot`??

Comment: @chicks I want to use the latest features of `gnuplot 5.0.1`. The version offered with `apt-get install gnuplot` is unfortunately an older version. To be more precise, I see it's version `4.6.4-2` at this time.

Comment: Even Ubuntu 15.04 only has 4.6.6.  RHEL7 is also on 4.6, but Fedora 22 has gnuplot 5. Try installing Fedora 22.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I incur the same problem as you.

It appears that the `gnuplot-5.0.1` is not Lua 5.3-compatible. It uses `luaL_checkint`, but Lua 5.3 is using `luaL_checkinteger`. You need to update the Gnuplot-5.0.1 file `term/lua.trm` as follows:

```
254       //t_num = luaL_checkint(L, 1);
255       t_num = luaL_checkinteger(L, 1); 
…
289       //t_num = luaL_checkint(L, 1);
290       t_num = luaL_checkinteger(L, 1);
```

Then, `make` and `make install`. It's OK in my Ubuntu 14.04